# How to type \measuredangle in PlainTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, plain-tex

I'm trying to do some geometry problem in PlainTex but I've found just `\angle` for angle representation. But I need `\measuredangle` that works in LaTeX.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\input amssym
$\measuredangle A = \pi/4$
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. PLainTeX cannot find amssum. Should I download it somewhere? Thanks

Comment: @JanKaifer Did you misspell?  It is `amssym`, not `amssum`.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have not misspelled. `! I can't find file \`amssym'. l.11 \input amssym`

Comment: @JanKaifer That is unusual.  I am confident that it, just as `amssymb.sty`, are part of TeX/LaTeX's standard distribution.  I am not sure what engine and distribution you are using.  I am using MikTeX, and my log file finds the file in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\plain\amsfonts\amssym.tex`.  I'm not sure what else to tell you at this point.  However, it can be found here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/source, and placed in your working directory.

Comment: I use pdfcsplain and I added `amssym.tex` and `amsym.def` to my `$TEXINPUTS` and it works like charm. Thanks.